# Optimizing JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Jquery code that looks like this. Is there a way to optimize this code? What happens if the image doesn't have a title attribute? Should I insert a case for using the value of the alt attribute as a backup and If I'm chaining the `.attr()` function multiple times, then it'd be cleaner code I you just ran the `.attr()` function a single time passing a value pair object of all my properties to the function. How can I do this ?

```
$(function() {

    $('.component-individual-detail-profile').each(function() {
        var $self = $(this), $images = $self.find('.photos');

        $images.find('li').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var thumb = $(this);
            $images.find('.selected')
                .attr('src', thumb.find('img').attr('src'))
                .attr('alt', thumb.find('img').attr('alt'))
                .attr('title', thumb.find('img').attr('title'));

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: replace to `var thumbImg = $(this).find('img')`

Comment: and use it `thumbImg.attr('src')...`

Comment: If I'm going to chain the .attr() function multiple times, then it'd be cleaner code if I just ran the .attr() function a single time passing a value pair object of all your properties to the function. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the attributes in a array, and cache the `$thumb.find('img')` selector:

```
$('.component-individual-detail-profile').each(function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  var $images = $self.find('.photos');

  $images.find('li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $thumb = $(this).find('img');
    var $selected = $images.find('.selected');
    $.each(['src', 'alt', 'title'], function(index, attrName){
      $selected.attr(attrName, $thumb.attr(attrName));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. One more question..  there's no reason to declare the $self variable. How can I make $(this) inline?

Comment: And why did we take out the document ready ? When I try and out that back in the code doesn't work

Comment: If I'm going to chain the .attr() function multiple times, then it'd be cleaner code if I just ran the .attr() function a single time passing a value pair object of all your properties to the function. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `var thumb = $(this).find("img")` for starters? Anywhere your code repeats function calls, you're probably doing something wrong.

Regarding "what if there is no attribute", you can do `thumb.attr('title') || thumb.attr('alt')`, using the logical or (`||`) to provide a value if the first one doesn't exist.

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), you can do...

```
$images.find('.selected').attr({
    src: thumb.attr('src'),
    alt: thumb.attr('alt'),
    title: thumb.attr('title') || thumb.attr('alt')
});
```